# MVC4 Razor confused about braces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a fairly simple question for all the Razor experts out there.  I'm trying to make a jQuery $.ajax() call to a URL, using Url.Content() to translate the home-relative path into an root-relative path.  In so doing, Razor is getting a bit confused about where the end of my @section is located.  I'd prefer to be able to specify the URL inline, but when I do that, Razor thinks that the end of the $.ajax() parameter list is the end of my @section.  I'm using @section because I want to use layouts to place my javascript at the bottom of each file.  Why is Razor getting so confused?  I've even tried using @(Url.Content(...)), but that doesn't work either.

Also, is this the best way to approach the problem?  I'm using the ASP.NET MVC 4 Preview.

***This works:***

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        var getMessagesUrl = '@Url.Content("~/Logging/GetMessages")';

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: getMessagesUrl,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('tbody').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

***This doesn't:***

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Logging/GetMessages")',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('tbody').html(result);
                }
            }); //Razor thinks this is the curly-brace that ends the section!
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: I tried both of these in an empty site and they both work fine, you sure its not just a typo somewhere?

Comment: Are you using MVC4 or MVC3?  I'm starting to think it could be a bug in the ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor parser.  I could have sworn that this worked fine in ASP.NET MVC 3...

Comment: Ah yeah this was 3, let me try in 4, it may very well just be a bug there.

Comment: For some @&^! reason, I can't set up an MVC3 project or I'd test it myself.... Thanks Paul

Comment: Confirmed on MVC4, must be a razor bug, nice find

Comment: Oh wait, think I found the issue, posted an answer, I think its the less than symbol in the comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all of the help, folks.

It looks like it must have been a bug in the ASP.NET MVC 4 Preview.  I just upgraded to the ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta which came out on February 15, and the problem is now completely gone.

Comment: '~/Logging/GetMessages' on clent side? You're lost!
Plus, the question was about the razor parser bug - "not coding" is not a  work around :)

Comment: $.ajax({url: '~/Logging/GetMessages',  //COOL!
- what kind of fix is this where you just post the ServerSide url containing the ~ home symbol on client side?

That won't work, so your solution is not really a fix / work around to the RAZOR bug, since the page won't work with your link anyway

Comment: This bug was fixed in VS2012 RC.

Answer (score 9):

This is likely down to the behaviour of the parser. When it encounters the `@` symbol, the parser switches to code mode and will read the implicit expression `Url.Content("~/Logging.GetMessages")` (well, actually it will read until the `'` symbol, determine it is not a valid character in an expression and trackback to return until the end of the `)`. It's after this stage that the parser is getting a little confused with your view because it's likely in code mode when it encounters the final `}` character, and thinks it is the end of of a code span.

The reality is, you have to be quite careful when using javascript within a razor view with C#. The transitions to code are explicit, e.g. `@` and after a `{`, but the transitions to markup are a little harder to determine.

Razor aside, my recommendation would be to stick your javascript application code in an external file, and take advantage of data-* attributes to convey meta information to your application code, e.g:

```
<script id="messageScript" type="text/javascript"
    src="/Scripts/messages.js" 
    data-messages="@Url.Content("~/Logging/GetMessages")"></script>
```

Which you can access as:

```
(function($) {

    $(function() {
        var $this = $("#messageScript");
        $.ajax({
            url: $this.attr("data-messages"),
            type: "html",
            success: function(result) {
                $("tbody").html(result);
            }
        });
    });

})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: That's a pretty cool way of passing information into the JS file... I'd been wondering of a way to do that for a while.  What about the idea of globally defining these paths and using them in yet another script?  (Though, in all honesty, I still can't see why an explicit @(Url.Content(...)) call still fails...

Comment: @DaveMarkle If you wanted to declare them globally, you may want to move them into the head, using the same techique as above, but perhaps with a `link` or `meta` element?

Comment: For something like this, you could combine his method with the html, and take an unobtrusive approach: `<tbody data-ajax-html="@Url.Content(...)">` and then just `var $tbody = $('tbody'); $tbody.load($tbody.data('ajaxHtml'));`

Comment: Or even `$('[data-ajax-html]').each(function() { $(this).load($(this).data('ajaxHtml')); })`

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Dave's less than symbol was not causing the problem, he only added it in his question for illustrative purposes.

On MVC4 I was able to isolate the issue.  This would not compile:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Content("~/Logging/GetMessages")',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function (result) {
        $('tbody').html(result);
      }
    }); //<-- test
  });
</script>
```

But this would:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Content("~/Logging/GetMessages")',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function (result) {
        $('tbody').html(result);
      }
    }); //-- test
  });
</script>
```

Seems like it was just the **<** in the comment that was throwing it.

Comment: ah, I added that comment just for the post.  it's actually the only thing that's different between my code and what I posted...

Comment: Oh weird, your code compiles in MVC4 for me in a blank project using the most recent beta without comments.

Comment: Ah, you know, it's not that it doesn't *compile*, it actually does.  The problem is that everything after the comment where you see //-- test doesn't get rendered out to the page.  My question should have been clearer.

Comment: Oh, I get up to the script tag close, so its working for me as well.

Comment: The less than sign seems to be the trigger of the problem, for sure, but there are all kinds of things that come after it that can alter the outcome.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1773194.aspx/1?Razor+bug+Javascript+inside+of+a+section

Answer (score 1):

Matthew's answer pretty much explains the behaviour (although, to be honest, I can't reproduce your problem - nor see why it wouldn't work - both your examples run just fine here). For a different approach, you could dedicate an action/view to generated javascript variables (urls, settings, localized texts, whatever), i.e.:

```
// Could/should be OutputCached depending on the scenario
public ActionResult Globals()
{
   var model = new ClientGlobalsModel();

   // ClientGlobalsModel has a single (could be more) Dictionary<string, string>
   // (Urls) and a ToJSON() method which uses JavaScriptSerializer to serialize 
   // the object:
   model.Urls.Add("GetMessages", Url.Content("~/Logging/GetMessages"));

   // I mostly use this method for e.g. actions:
   model.Urls.Add("UploadImage", Url.Action("Upload", "Image"));

   Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";

   return View(model);
}
```

Globals.cshtml:

```
@model ClientGlobalsModel
@{
    Layout = null; // If you have a layout supplied in e.g. _ViewStart
}
var GLOBALS = @Model.ToJSON()
```

Yeah, this could have been a simple `Content()` result rather than a view - but when you have more globals (e.g. settings + urls + texts), you may want easier control over the script output and maybe serialize each dictionary individually. May also want to namespace that "GLOBALS" variable in some shared application namespace to avoid polluting the global scope.

(e.g.) Index.cshtml:

```
<script src="@Url.Action("Globals", "Client")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/main.js")"></script>
```

... which simply includes the output from /Client/Globals. And "main.js", into which we have now moved the rest of your script:

main.js (static):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.ajax({
      url: GLOBALS.Urls.GetMessages,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function (result) {
         $('tbody').html(result);
      }
   });
});
```

You can, of course, use the same kind of approach to output a few user/context/view-specific settings directly into the view. For a few URL's or data, the data-* attribute approach may be better depending on your tastes. I'm not a fan of stuffing *tons* of what's basically settings into attributes on every HTML page, though.

Comment: Its MVC4, I couldn't repro in MVC3 either, but can in MVC4.

Comment: Ah nm, it compiles for me without his comment with the less than symbol, guess it must be something with his environment.

Comment: @TheKaneda I like this approach to passing variables to the client but when I try this the return View() for the Globals action is returning HTML even with the Response.ContentType set to `application/javascript`. Is there anything else i need to do?  thanks

Comment: @sambomartin - is it returning a MIME-type of "text/html"? (because it shouldn't be). Or is it returning HTML in your view (in that case, you probably have a Layout interfering - see the code I just added to the view in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Seems to still be a problem with final MVC4 / Visual Studio 2010, but here is my fix:

```
@section jQueryDocumentReady
{
  @{
  <text>
     // All the javascript and bracers you want here
  </text>
  }
}
```