# Manually upgraded from MVC3 to MVC4 Beta and getting "not valid @" sign errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using Razor in both

Any page that using the @ sign.  Its almost like either the System.Web.WebPages or System.Web.Helpers are not able to determine the Views

Here is the actual error:

**"@" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.**

Here is my web.config that is in the /Views folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>

<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>

<!--
    Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
    after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
    MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
    To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
    controller or action.
-->
<pages
      validateRequest="false"
      pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
      pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
      userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
</pages>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This could be related to escaping @ sign.  So for example, how would you include a twitter username in a razor view.  We have @@@TwitterUsername today which works fine in MVC3, but not MVC4?  New way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out switching to MVC4 beta was not handling @@@ escapes properly

I have a twitter client where it will render a person's screen name in a view like this:

```
@@@TwitterUsername
```

This will render a @ with the escaped @@ and then render the twitter name with @TwitterUsername

This does not work with MVC4.  So I had to change to this and it worked fine:

```
@Html.Raw("@")@TwitterUsername
```

Not near as pretty, but it works.
Is there something not right with Razor parsing on MVC4 or am I not doing something right implementing it?

The output of this is:

@jordanshane

Answer (score 2):

Refer to MVC 4 [ReleaseNote](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806)

There is a section describing **Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to ASP.NET MVC 4**

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps these links will help:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1751597.aspx/1

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/09/compiling-mvc-views-in-a-build-environment.aspx

[MVC4 Razor confused about braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366169/mvc4-razor-confused-about-braces)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when upgrading from MVC3 to MVC4 when outputting a 'page' that is an Excel dump in Excel XML format.  For example, I had the following line in my XML page layout file:

*Doesn't* work:

```
<NumberFormat ss:Format="m/d/yyyy;@@"/>
```

The parser gave me the following error:

> **Parser Error Message:** ""/>" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

The Html.Raw("@") answer worked for me, and I wasn't readily able to find any reason for this behavior in the links that several other answers provided.  In case anyone is looking for a more terse looking solution, here's another possibility:

**Does** work:

```
<NumberFormat ss:Format="m/d/yyyy;@('@')"/>
```