# ASP.NET MVC3 - Dynamically create javascript from Action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got an MVC3 application in which I have javascript functions that have to call MVC Actions to either get data or redirect the page.

Currently the javascript is sitting in the cshtml file (using razor) so I can take advantage of `Url.Action(..)` and `Url.Content(..)` functions.

If I wanted to separate these files up, I'd lose the server side compilation of the files as the .js is not obviously handled by the razor engine.

Is it possible to create a cshtml view and return the content (Reponse.ContentType) as 'application/javascript' or is there another way I can achieved the desired result?

Thanks in advance

Sam

Comment: There's an example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366169/mvc4-razor-confused-about-braces/9367621#9367621) - and probably in other places. It's generally not recommended to use Razor for outputting "massive" amounts of javascript, but mostly you should be able to get around that, using one of the methods in that question.

Comment: It would probably be easier to just design your JS as a library you can initialize with the url's passed in from your view.

Comment: @TheKaneda - thanks for the link, I actually got this working before other answers.

Comment: @PaulTyng - thanks also, this was the proposed answer in the end!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or is there another way I can achieved the desired result?

There is actually. Design your javascript functions so that they take those urls as parameters. Then all you have to do is to leave the initialization call in your view and pass the required urls:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    myJsInitialize('@Url.Action("Foo")', '@Url.Content("~/bar")');
</script>
```

or another possibility is to have those urls as part of the DOM that your javascript is working with. For example let's suppose that you have a link and you wish to send an AJAX request when this link is clicked:

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me", "someaction", null, new { id = "mylink" })
```

and in your separate js file you would use the href attribute of the link which already contains the url:

```
$('#mylink').click(function() {
    $('#result').load(this.href);
    return false;
});
```

But what if you needed for example another url in this function. Let's suppose for example that you needed to call an action using AJAX when the selction of a dropdown changes. In this case you could use HTML5 `data-*` attributes on the dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedItem,
    Model.Items,
    new { 
        id = "myddl",
        data_url = Url.Action("someaction")
    }
)
```

and then in your separate javascript file:

```
$('#myddl').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $.post(url, { value: selectedValue }, function(result) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

See how we no longer need to have the javascript functions depend on server side helpers such as `Url.Action` or `Url.Content`? This allows you to put them in separate javascript files without worrying that your application will stop working when you deploy it in a IIS virtual directory for example.

Comment: thanks for input Darin, some of what you've suggested, whilst good suggestions wouldn't help my scenario.  I simply need to populate page specific server vars into the client javascript - but not within the cshtml page.  Your first suggestion would do the trick!  its quite similar to @Mystere Man's answer, except using a function to set the local vars. thanks all.

Comment: @sambomartin I would definitely use a function for initialization, it helps to deal with script ordering, if scripts just execute immediately its sometimes hard to initialize them properly and definitely makes them difficult to load asynchronously when they have dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

A little known feature of script blocks is that you can provide a src attribute AND code in the block.  So, you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Myscript.js")">
    var myurl = `@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")`;
</script>
```

Then, in your script you can reference myurl.